# How can I port this selectlist-method from asp.net MVC to .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In my old Asp.Net MVC-project I had a nice method on my formmodel which could generate selectlistitems for my views.

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetYears()
    {
        for (int counter = 2; counter <= 15; counter++)
        {
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = counter + " year", Value = counter.ToString() };
        }
    }
```

I could then call it like:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Year, MyFormModel.GetYears(), "Choose     here", new { @class = "my-class" })
```

I am now trying to do the same in .Net Core 2, but cant seem to get it to work.

Any ideas?

Tried calling the same method like, but it wont work.

```
            <select asp-for="Year" asp-items="Model.GetYears" class="my-class"> </select>
```

Comment: `Model.GetYears` means you need an `IEumerable<SelectListItem> GetYears` property in your model. Have you added that?

Comment: In my old model in MVC I did not need to have that as the method was available in the view. Has this changed in .net core?

Comment: Then the equivalent would be `asp-items="MyFormModel.GetYears()"` but don't know if that works in core (but you should always be using view model with `IEnumerable<SelectListItems>` in either framework)

Comment: Yes, that is what the question is regarding. I have tried  <select asp-for="Year" asp-items="Model.GetYears()" class="my-class"> </select>  and it does not seem to work in .Net Core.

Comment: cant you use by defining `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property

Comment: You said you used `Model.GetYears()` but it would need to be `MyFormModel.GetYears()` (static methods can be accessed only via its class name).

Comment: @StephenMuecke This was what is missing. My bad. Please add as a answer and I will accept. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you attempted - `asp-items="Model.GetYears"` means that your view model needs a property which is

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetYears { get; set }
```

which you would populate in the GET method before passing the model to the view by calling your static `GetYears()` method.

If you do want to use the static method in the view, then it needs to be

```
<select asp-for="Year" asp-items="MyFormModel.GetYears()" .. > </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by defining `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property in model,

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years{
     get{
         return GetYears();
        }
}
```

and use in your view by,

```
 <select asp-for="Year" asp-items="Model.Years" class="my-class"> </select>
```